# How to detect duplicate values in multidimensional associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-unique

I have an associative multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customer_name] => John Dow
            [customer_email] => john@example.com
            [customer_mobile] => 1236547895
            [birth_date] => 12/1/1996
            [status] => Enable
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [customer_name] => Alex
            [customer_email] => alex@example.com
            [customer_mobile] => 4563214785
            [birth_date] => 19/1/1996
            [status] => Enable
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [customer_name] => Arina
            [customer_email] => arina@example.com
            [customer_mobile] => 963214785
            [birth_date] => 25/1/1996
            [status] => Enable
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [customer_name] => Atom
            [customer_email] => atom@example.com
            [customer_mobile] => 5214789632
            [birth_date] => 12/1/1998
            [status] => Enable
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [customer_name] => Jennifer
            [customer_email] => jennifer@example.com
            [customer_mobile] => 4563214785
            [birth_date] => 12/2/1996
            [status] => Enable
        )
)
```

Now I want to inspect similar values in `customer_mobile` and `customer_email` from each other to reduce redundancies. Contact number and email addresses must be non-redundant.

So please guide me, how can  I achieve this? Thanks :)

Comment: post the desired result

Comment: i don't want any result . i just want to check if any customer have duplicate contact number as well as email address. it return as flag - true

means this array have contains redundancy

Comment: you wrote *it return as flag* - one flag for all items OR for each item separately?

Comment: on flag for all item - if 1 contact number repeated 2 or more times as well as email. entire array will be discarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is:

```
<?php

$data = [
  [
    'name' => 'name 1',
    'phone' => '12341234',
    'email' => 'test@web.com'
  ],
  [
    'name' => 'name 2',
    'phone' => '12341234',
    'email' => 'test@web1.com'
  ],
  [
    'name' => 'name 3',
    'phone' => '4322342',
    'email' => 'test@web1.com'
  ],
  [
    'name' => 'name 4',
    'phone' => '1234123423',
    'email' => 'test@web1.com'
  ],
  [
    'name' => 'name 5',
    'phone' => '12341266634',
    'email' => 'test@eqweqwweb.com'
  ],
];

$phones = [];
$emails = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $contact) {
  if (array_search($contact['phone'], $phones) !== false || array_search($contact['email'], $emails) !== false) {
    unset($data[$key]);
  } else {
    $phones[] = $contact['phone'];
    $emails[] = $contact['email'];
  }
}

var_dump($data);
```

and in result you'll get:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    'name' =>
    string(6) "name 1"
    'phone' =>
    string(8) "12341234"
    'email' =>
    string(12) "test@web.com"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(3) {
    'name' =>
    string(6) "name 3"
    'phone' =>
    string(7) "4322342"
    'email' =>
    string(13) "test@web1.com"
  }
  [4] =>
  array(3) {
    'name' =>
    string(6) "name 5"
    'phone' =>
    string(11) "12341266634"
    'email' =>
    string(18) "test@eqweqwweb.com"
  }
}
```

this is just example.

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't need to know **which**, but only **if**, you could use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) + [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php): ([run](https://3v4l.org/N31fI))

```
$cm = array_column($arr, 'customer_mobile');
if($cm != array_unique($cm)){
    echo 'There are duplicates in customer_mobile';
}

$ce = array_column($arr, 'customer_email');
if($cm != array_unique($ce)){
    echo 'There are duplicates in customer_email';
}
```

---

If you need to **match both** email and mobile, do it in the same `if`:

```
if($cm != array_unique($cm) && $ce != array_unique($ce)){
    echo 'There are duplicates in both customer_mobile and customer_email';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way (i generate code from head so it can have bug - but idea should be clear) (i assume you array name is $persons):

```
$emails = [];
$mobiles = [];

$discard = false;
foreach($persons as $person) 
{
   $email = $person['customer_email'];

   if(!isset($emails[$email])) {
       $emails[$email] = $person;
   } else {
      $emails[$email]['redundant_email']=true;
      $person['redundant_email']=true;
      $discard = true;
   }

   $mobile = $person['customer_mobile'];

   if(!isset($mobiles[$mobile])) {
       $mobiles[$mobile] = $person;
   } else {
       $mobiles[$mobile]['redundant_mobile']=true;
       $person['redundant_mobile']=true;
       $discard = true;
   }
}
```

As result each person with redundat mobile or email have set field `redundant_email` or `redundant_mobile` to true. The variable `$discard=true` says that array is redundant.

Comment: there is no any value in array..!

Comment: if 1 contact number repeated 2 or more times as well as email. entire array will be discarded.. how can i achienve this?

Comment: @DevendraSingh - again I make correction due to your new requirements - now you have boolean answer in `$discard` variable as well as 'flags' in redundant persons

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `foreach`. You need only traverse the array one time, use the email and mobile as unique key, the elements with the same unique key will only keep the last one. If you want the results use number index, use `array_values()` on the `$result`.

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $v)
{
  $result[$v['customer_email'] . $v['customer_mobile']] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution and is working fine.

```
    $name = array_column($array, 'name');
    $filteredKeys = array_unique($name);

    foreach (array_keys($filteredKeys) as $key => $value) {
    $filtered [] = $array[$value];
    }
      return  $filtered;
    }
```

Comment: There are two closing curly brackets, but only one opening; something seems to be missing here!

Answer (score -1):

My answer would be, that you should not do this in PHP at all. In your presented case the data should be checked/validated/filtered only on the database side. If there are duplicates, then you don't have to fetch data at all!

Run a query to just check for redundancies in db. Only if no redundancy fetch the data.

If there is a lot of data, then you'll spare a big data fetch and loop through data from the beginning.

Good luck.